# How I can show the result of an input and its permutations?

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, permutation

I need to show all permutations of the entered value in an input of maximum 5 characters

I make this Codepen example but doesn't works fine

https://codepen.io/alonsoct00/pen/WBeXEp

My script:

```
<script>
     function permute(a) {
     if (a.length < 5) return [a];
     var c, d, b = [];
     for (c = 0; c < a.length; c++) {
      var e = a.splice(c, 1),
        f = permute(a);
      for (d = 0; d < f.length; d++) b.push([e].concat(f[d]));
      a.splice(c, 0, e[0])
      }
     return b

    }

   function permuteval() {
   var txtval = document.getElementById('permute_this').value;
   document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
   (permute([txtval]).join("\n"));

    }
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a spread operator:

```
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = (permute([...txtval]).join("\n"));
```

not sure if this is the exact output you're looking for

https://codepen.io/jfitzsimmons/pen/RmNZGP

Also, I like this code for permutations:

```
const permutations = arr => {
  if (arr.length <= 2) return arr.length === 2 ? [arr, [arr[1], arr[0]]] : arr;
  return arr.reduce(
    (acc, item, i) =>
      acc.concat(
        permutations([...arr.slice(0, i), ...arr.slice(i + 1)]).map(val => [item, ...val])
      ),
    []
  );
};
EXAMPLES
permutations([1, 33, 5]); // [ [ 1, 33, 5 ], [ 1, 5, 33 ], [ 33, 1, 5 ], [ 33, 5, 1 ], [ 5, 1, 33 ], [ 5, 33, 1 ] ]
```

https://30secondsofcode.org/

Answer (score 1):

you're replacing the innerHTML with the new content.

```
var txtval = document.getElementById('permute_this').value + '<br>';    
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += 
   (permute([txtval]));
```

should do the trick. there's no point using Array.prototype.join() here and `\n` won't work the way you want to in HTML.

also this is probably the most convoluted way to display the content of the 
why not just take the raw input and parse it?